# Django internalization - changing current language does not work

Tags: django, localization, gettext

I want to localize my REST app, and have read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/). Seems like I've done everything accordingly, and yet can't get the message in my exception appear in Russian on client side.

The view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def foo(request):
    if serialized.is_valid():
        activation_key = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        email = request.data['email']
        user_language = 'ru'
        translation.activate(user_language)
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
        try:
            # SMTPRecipientsRefused error generating code
        except SMTPRecipientsRefused:
            return Response({'msg': _('Invalid email address'),
                             'object': None}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
     # ...
```

And here's what I have done to tackle localization.

1. Set up gettext for Windows downloading the corresponding files from [this source](https://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/dependencies/)
2. Ran the `django-admin compilemessages` command and successfully generated the `.po` files
3. Opened the generated `.po` file and filled in the necessary translation
4. Edited the middleware to include all necessary elements

The `.po` file looks like this:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-01-04 19:49+0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=4; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n"
"%10<=4 && (n%100<12 || n%100>14) ? 1 : n%10==0 || (n%10>=5 && n%10<=9) || (n"
"%100>=11 && n%100<=14)? 2 : 3);\n"

#: .\rest\views.py:46
msgid "Invalid email address"
msgstr "Некорректный почтовый адрес"
```

The middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
     #...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

Any help on what I am missing here ?

Comment: please give me your middleware...

Comment: Middleware ? I don't have any. Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` it is important to include at `MIDDLEWARE` in the `settings.py`... hope this article can help.. https://python.web.id/blog/how-to-implement-django-internationalization/